# run command behavior with limitation on number of signatures in alloy

Tags: alloy

The first code, couldn't find any instances at Alloy Analyzer 4.2, but the second one, finds well!
What is the differences? My expectation is that, # > 0 and # = 1 acts as the same, when I execute "run show for 1".

1:

```
sig Fruit {}
pred show() { #Fruit > 0}
run show for 1
```

2:

```
sig Fruit {}
pred show() { #Fruit = 1}
run show for 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a command you will see that the bitwidth (which determines the max Int for Alloy) is 0.

```
   Executing "Run show for 1"

   Solver=sat4j Bitwidth=0 MaxSeq=0 SkolemDepth=1 Symmetry=20
   0 vars. 0 primary vars. 0 clauses. 2ms.
   No instance found. Predicate may be inconsistent. 0ms.
```

You can change this by explicitly changing bitwidth:

```
sig Fruit {}
pred show() { #Fruit>0}
run show for 1 but 2 int

Executing "Run show for 1 but 2 int"
   Solver=sat4j Bitwidth=2 MaxSeq=1 SkolemDepth=1 Symmetry=20
   1 vars. 1 primary vars. 1 clauses. 3ms.
   . found. Predicate is consistent. 3ms.
```

I think when you use '>' operator you will need bitwidth but when you use '=' it is not required.

Working with Int is really **discouraged** in Alloy.